# Using GeoFire with Firebase on Android, but can't find the DatabaseReference Class

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, geofire

I am trying to connect to my Firebase account and make a query using a specific location to see if there are any GeoFire positions in it. For this I am using the official tutorials, but haven't been able to create a Geofire object. Here is what the Tutorial says:

> A GeoFire object is used to read and write geo location data to your
>   Firebase database and to create queries. To create a new GeoFire
>   instance you need to attach it to a Firebase database reference.

```
DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("path/to/geofire");
GeoFire geoFire = new GeoFire(ref);
```

Following this tutorial, I run into the problem that Android Studio cannot resolve DatabaseReference symbol.

If I try to pass the Firebase object itself:

```
Firebase mLocs = new Firebase("https://example.firebaseio.com/Locations");
GeoFire geoFire = new GeoFire(mLocs);
```

I get an error saying that

> com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference cannot be converted to
>   com.firebase.client.Firebase

My Firebase object was appropriately instantiated and its context declared.

```
Firebase.setAndroidContext(this);
```

Any ideas what might be going wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The tutorial is using the old Firebase SDK.

Follow [this guide](https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup) on how to setup the new Firebase SDK and then add the realtime database feature.

So, you will add these dependencies in the `build.gradle` file

```
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:9.4.0'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:9.4.0'
```

Then, you can create `GeoFire` instance using the guide from [GeoFire for Android github page](https://github.com/firebase/geofire-java)